# How to get coordinates from a Wikipedia page using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, geolocation, wikipedia-api

I want to get the coordinates of a given Wikipedia page. I tried to use the Wikipedia API, however the only relevant method is the geosearch() that returns a page given a pair of coordinates and i want the exact opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about doing it with the Wikipedia API, but it can easily be done separately.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
req = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calgary").text
soup = bs(req, 'lxml')
latitude = soup.find("span", {"class": "latitude"})
longitude = soup.find("span", {"class": "longitude"})
print(latitude.text, longitude.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You've not mentioned which Python library you're using but in general, e.g. for getting the coordinates of the [Washington, D.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.) article using the [Geosearch API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Geosearch) one may use the following URL:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=coordinates&titles=Washington,%20D.C.&%20format=json